# Parallel object initialization in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Normally I would use async with specific function calls, then use await.  But I am not sure how to implement that with object creation.  I want to trigger the creation of my three classes, and then await for all of there init functions to finish.  So my output would look like -

```
First Class
Second Class
Third Class
First Class done
Second Class done
Third Class done
```

(class order doesn't matter)

```
class First:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("First Class")
        sleep(60)
        print("First Class done")

class Second:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("Second Class")
        sleep(60)
        print("Second Class done")

class Third:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("Third Class")
        sleep(60)
        print("Third Class done")
```

```
def main():
    f = First(1)
    s = Second(2)
    t = Third(3)
    #await f,s,t init functions to finish.
```

Comment: Use multi-threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Threads to do that. But be aware of the GIL. If you really want to have performance improvements then you should use Subprocesses. But anyways here is the code for your problem:

```
import threading 
from time import sleep

class First:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("First Class")
        #sleep(60)
        print("First Class done")
        self.x = x

class Second:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("Second Class")
        #sleep(60)
        print("Second Class done")
        self.x = x

class Third:
    def __init__(self, x):
        print("Third Class")
        #sleep(60)
        print("Third Class done")
        self.x = x

def assign(lst,i,Class):
    lst[i] = Class(i)

def main():
    lst = [None,None,None]
    t1=threading.Thread(target=assign,args=[lst,0,First])
    t2=threading.Thread(target=assign,args=[lst,1,Second])
    t3=threading.Thread(target=assign,args=[lst,2,Third])
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    print(lst[0].x,lst[1].x,lst[2].x)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look at subprocesses, because each of these classes are very intensive.